# Extremely strange behaviour: Django's cache.get method returns different values

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached, couchbase

I 'm using django's cache backend to interact with the moxi-client that follows the memcached protocol.

My test code is structured like this.

```
from django.core.cache import cache
key = "test_object_key"
max_errors = 15
errors = 0
total_runs = 0
unexpected_objects_returned = []
while(errors<max_errors):
    total_runs += 1
    obj = cache.get(key)
    if(type(obj)  == ExpectedObject):
        continue
    else:
        unexpected_objects_returned.append(obj)
        errors += 1
```

The very first time the right value is returned. For the next 10 calls, the method returns the exact same objects in the same order. The objects are either a list of chars (stored through another process under different keys) or None. After the first 10 hits, the method starts returning the right object.

If I instantiate the cache object using the following code

```
from django.core.cache import get_cache
cache = get_cache('default')
```

Everything runs as expected. It is because of this I'm expecting the issue to be somewhere in Django and not further downstream in either the moxi-client or couchbase.

I would implement this solution however I have a huge Django project and making sure that every file contains it is going to be a pain. Any hints towards a solution would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Django 1.3.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the internal key prefixing that django does? I had problems with it and memcached so I ended up using `cache._cache` to access the memcached client itself.

Comment: The internal key caching should still mean that I get the same object even if its the wrong object. The issue is that the cache returns different objects as it cycles through the same key that i specify.

Comment: Oh I see, you are getting different objects returned.